# Is there any flaw in my solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, evm

Imagine a simple contract that collects Eth. Is there any way to manipulate this such that after users send funds, this.balance =/= max_val? Can this be gamed in a way that will allow isFinished() to never be able to get past the require statement?

```
uint max_val = 3 * 10** 18; // Can send up to 3 ETH
bool finished = false; // Not finished

// Function to send ETH
function sendEth() payable {
    require(!finished); // Cannot be over
    require(this.balance <= max_val);  // Contribution must be less than or equal to contribution max
}

// Function to finish sending
function isFinished() {
    require(!finished); // Cannot be finished. Cannot be called twice.
    require(this.balance == max_val);  // Must have collected max ETH
    finished = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments first:

1. Why is the function that receives ether called sendEth shouldn't it be called `receiveEth` because that's what it does?
2. Why not use modifiers which make you code significantly easier to understand? Easy to understand code == less buggy code.

My guess is that balance is updated after the function, but I'm not sure (see comment below).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Testing {

    uint max_val = 3 * 10 ** 18;
    bool finished = false;

    modifier notFinished() {
       if (finished)
           revert();
       _;
    }

    // NOTE: Not sure if this.balance is already updated with
    // the new msg.value (my guess is no). I will edit this code
    // if someone corrects me.
    function receiveEth() notFinished() payable {

       // If the tx would go over max, revert
       if (msg.value + this.balance > max_val)
           revert();

       // If we will have exactly max, we're done
       if (msg.value + this.balance == max_val)
           finished = true;

       // Otherwise, accept the eth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, it's trivial to send more than `max_val` because you don't check if `msg.value` is more than `max_value - this.balance`. You need to add `require(msg.value <= max_value - this.balance)` inside `sendEth()`.

Comment: It is my understanding that right when `sendEth()` is called, `this.balance` gets updated, prior to going through any lines of the function. If this is the case, then wouldn't `require(msg.value <= max_value - this.balance)` be redundant?

Comment: I believe that balance is updated afterward, but I can't find that in docs.